# $A$ def. pos.$\implies a_{ii} >0, \;\max_{1\leq i, j\leq n}|a_{ij}| = \max_{1\leq i, j\leq n}|a_{ii}| >0.$ When you can reverse the inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^N$ be a square matrix. It is well known that if $A$ is positive definite, thus
$$a_{ii} >0 \quad\mbox{ and }\quad \max_{1\leq i, j\leq n}|a_{ij}| = \max_{1\leq i, j\leq n}|a_{ii}| >0.$$

My question is: does a sort of "viceversa" hold? I mean, if $a_{ii} >0$ and $\max_{1\leq i, j\leq n}|a_{ij}| = \max_{1\leq i, j\leq n}|a_{ii}| >0$ it is true that $A$ is positive definite?

About me, the answer is not, unless you deal with some special case (for example, if $A$ is a diagonal matrix).

Could anyone please help me saying if a viceversa holds?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean strictly diagonally dominant matrix,
$$|a_{ii}|>\sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}|\qquad i=1,\ldots, n.$$

If a real symmetric matrix $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant with $a_{ii}>0$,
that is
$$a_{ii}>\sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}|\qquad i=1,\ldots, n.$$

then it is positive definite.

For the proof, we only need to show all its eigenvalues are positive.

Assume $Ax=\lambda x$, with $x_i=\max_j |x_j|>0$ (if necessary, consider $-x$).

Then $\lambda x_i=a_{ii} x_i+\sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij}x_{j}\geq (a_{ii}-\sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}|)x_i>0$, that is $\lambda>0$.

Here we use the fact $x+\sum_j y_j\geq x-\sum_j |y_j|$ for $x,y_j\in \mathbb R$, that is
$$\begin{aligned}
a_{ii} x_i+\sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij}x_{j}&\geq a_{ii} x_i -\sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}|\cdot |x_j|,\qquad &&a_{ii},x_i>0\\
&\geq a_{ii} x_i -\sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}| x_i,\qquad &&x_i\geq |x_j|,\quad j\neq i\\
&=(a_{ii}-\sum_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}|)x_i,\qquad &&a_{ii}>\sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}|\\
&>0
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But could you justify the first inequality "$\geq$" in the last line?

Comment: @C.Bishop Some comments are added in the answer.

Comment: just another question about your proof. If you suppose $|a_{ii}| >\sum_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}|$ nothing change in your proof except that you write $|a_{ii}|$ instead of $a_{ii}$. But if I take the matrix $\begin{vmatrix} -4& 2& 1\\ 2& 4& -1\\ 1& -1& 3\end{vmatrix}$, it is strictly diagonally predominant but it is not definite positive? (you can see, for example, that it has a negative eigenvalue). Could you help me please again?

Comment: @C.Bishop Because in the first step, what we use is exactly $x+y\geq x-|y|$. Compute the first line with $x_1>0$.

Comment: Sorry, we use the inequality $|x+y|\geq |x| +|y|$, isn't it? Maybe I am missing something

Comment: @C.Bishop With $a>0$ and $|a|=\max\{|a|,|b|,|c|\}$, we have $4a+2b+c\geq 4a-|2b|-|c|\geq 4a-2a-a=a>0$. But we can only get $-4a+2b+c\geq -7a$.